# Probability of $A \cup A$

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory, boolean-algebra

Studying for an exam and just want to check this "degenerate" case.

I know in boolean algebra, A + A = A. So I assume that same would hold true in set notation. My proof is as follows:

$P(A \cup A) = P(A) + P(A) - P(A \cap A) = P(A)$

I couldn't find this anywhere else but just wanted to double check here.

As a sidenote, I guess this means that $P(A \cap A) = P(A \cup A) = P(A)$?

Thanks so much.

Comment: The thing is that, as sets, $A\cup A = A\cap A = A$, so yes, the same is true for probability.

Comment: The proof is just that $A \cup A = A$ and therefore $P(A \cup A) = A$. Note that any $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ is also a Boolean subalgebra of $P(X)$.

Comment: got it, thank you guys so much!